# how to set style only when screen size is less than screen height?

Tags: html, css, screen

I am looking for the best way to set a specific style on an element but I only want it to apply when the screen size is less than the screen height. So far I am doing it this way

```
@media (max-width: 320px) and (max-height : 480px) {
}
@media (max-width: 360px) and (max-height : 640px) {  
}
@media (max-width: 768px) and (max-height : 1024px) {
}
@media (max-width: 800px) and (max-height : 1280px) {
}
@media (max-width: 980px) and (max-height : 1280px) {
}
```

Is there a simplier way to do this or is this the only way?
Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the best way,but you can try with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Two Methods:


1. JavaScript:

```
if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
    portrait = true;
}else{
   portrait = false;
}
```

2. CSS:

```
 @media screen and (orientation:portrait) { … }
 @media screen and (orientation:landscape) { … }
```

Out of these two in CSS, choose whichever you want depending on `height>width` or `width>height`